# Using SQLite to make a javascript game with account functionality

Tags: javascript, sqlite, web

I am very new to learning SQLite and was wondering how I would go about making a javascript-based web game with it. I need it to have a function account system with stored variables for each account, and I haven't the slightest clue how to do this. Is SQLite even what I should be using?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Still havent gotten any answers or suggestions, is it possible the community missed this question?

Comment: You are not likely to get answers or suggestions; this question is likely to be closed. It is [not on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Perhaps start with an internet search for "javascript sqlite".